# There is an error in XML document

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, soap, xml-deserialization

I am developing a WinForms application. For DB transaction the WinForms application refers to PHP webservice. Someimes the functions in the Webservice behaves strangely. The function generates the exception:

> There is an error in XML document (2, 421)

with the inner exception:

> {"The specified type was not recognized: name='AccessOptions', namespace='......', at ."}

The most strange thing is that if I test the same function from PHP application, That works fine but in case of .NET application, it generates the above exception. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to answer without example of the xml that is playing up...

Comment: I am not using any XML. As I am invoking the PHP webservice from my application, That service returning the output in form of array of generic objects. Then Why I am getting the error "There is an error in XML document"

Comment: then perhaps use a network sniffer or debugging proxy (fiddler) to glance at the xml on the wire. Something is wrong. Probably a server error page.

Comment: Your objects don't match the PHP web service's XML output.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for sure without the xml or wsdl, but my guess would be that the wsdl is incomplete, and the type AccessOptions is not there in the wsdl. So .NET doesn't know how to deserialize that type. PHP isn't that strictly typed, so it may go easy on the missing type.

Anash